# Preserve Word list numbering when importing file into DOORS

Tags: ms-word, ibm-doors

I am importing a requirements document in created in Word into a DOORS module. I also want to be able to export the DOORS module back into a Word document and have them look mostly-similar. What is the easiest way to do this?

There are two options to do this that I can see:

1. In Word, use the DOORS add-in to "Export to DOORS"
2. In DOORS, use "Import -> Rich Text Format" (on the Word file saved as a RTF)

In Option 1, the numbering for the items in a list are not preserved. In Option 2, the line numbering is preserved, but upon exporting back to Word, the list Word styles are all "normal" and I lose all the formatting and indenting.

In Option 1, I can take advantage of the "Paragraph Style" attribute that is populated when the initial export is performed to make the resulting Word document look like the original. In Option 2, I do not see this option/attribute available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way in DOORS/Word to handle this natively. The best solution I could find is to first convert the Word auto-numbering to actual text using the VBA method `ConvertNumbersToText()`. Doing this allows me to keep the formatting/indentation in DOORS and also have the ability to export the database back to Word and have it look the same/similar.

The only minor issue is that the resulting document no longer uses the Word auto-numbering. This is not an issue for my purposes.